# My wiznet 5500 ethernet circuit is not working ( using it ESP32 s3 )

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, ethernet, esp32, network

I made a custom PCB board with w5500 ethernet IC and ESP32 S3 module and it's not working at all, even the RJ45 connector LEDS aren't responding when powering the circuit.
here's the schematics of my projects.[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you connect all 7 GND pins of the W5500? On some of my boards I had a problem with the power on reset of the W5500. The chip needed an explicit external low reset signal of more than 250 ms for a proper startup. Without this, it often was in an unrecoverable state.

Comment: @Jens yes sir , i connected all the GND with the ground plane